# How to make middle element stretch horizontally over all available space

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have a basic form

```
<div class="outer">
    <label>Label</label>
    <input/>
    <button>Search!</button>
</div>
```

that I want to display inline with these basic declarations:

```
.outer{
    width: 100%;
}

.outer, label, button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem is - how to pull the Search button to the right and make the input element stretch horizontally over the available space?

Here is [a JSBin where I attempted this effect](http://jsbin.com/kigaqe/1/edit) but didn't know how to stretch the input. I don't know the total width, so can't control the width of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use floating:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <label>Label</label>
    <button>Search!</button>
    <div><input/></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer{
  border: solid thin;
  overflow: hidden; /* Clear float */
}
.outer > label {
  float: left; /* Push left */
}
.outer > button {
  float: right; /* Push right */
}
.outer > div {
  overflow: hidden; /* Make it take remaining space */
}
.outer > div > input {
  width: 100%;  /* Make it fill its parent */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Avoid extra width because of borders */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/mawumura/1/edit)

Comment: Note that if you don't place the input in a wrapper element, it won't work: http://jsbin.com/mawumura/2/edit

Comment: Many thanks, really tricky how the `overflow` is used, is it really needed on `.outer` - I removed it with no apparent effect?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev It's to make sure that the floating elements remain inside outer. Maybe not needed in this concrete case, but I would use it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS tables:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <label>Label</label>
  <div><input/></div>
  <button>Search!</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.outer > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.outer > div  {
  width: 100%; /* Make it take as much space as possible */
}
.outer > div > input {
  width: 100%; /* Make it fill its parent */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Avoid extra width because of borders */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/mawumura/3/edit)

Comment: Note that if you don't place the input in a wrapper element, it won't work: http://jsbin.com/mawumura/5/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexible boxes:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input/>
  <button>Search!</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.outer > input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/mawumura/4/edit)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work on IOS Safari, even with `width: 100%` on `.outer`, it doesn't expand to the end of the screen.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev It seems Safari needs `-webkit-` prefix to make it work. See [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Even with prefixes couldn't get it working in Firefox: http://jsbin.com/mawumura/15/edit

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev It's `display: flex` (or `-moz-flex` on old firefox). [This demo](http://jsbin.com/mawumura/16/edit) works on Firefox 18 (behind a pref).

Answer (score 1):

Change your css a title bit, try this

```
.outer label, .outer button {
  display: inline-block;
  width:10%
}
input {
  width:75%
}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really pull the Search to the right unless you calculate exactly the percentage. Still like the simplicity.